# How to pass "bin" as a GET parameter in WCF without receiving 404

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a .NET 4.0 WCF service that accepts GET requests.

The URL to access it looks like 
https://api.mysite.com/MyService.svc/FunctionName/Param1/Param2/Param3

When Param3 is the word "bin" I get a 404

This is strange because if the WCF is malformed it shows me a "Endpoint not found" error

I realized it only did this when passing in "bin" as any of the params

How can I accept this word without it first looking for a physical path and replying with a 404 ?

Comment: This happens passing `bin` as *any* parameter or just the 3rd? If it's the latter than it's more likely an endpoint mapping issue rather than the use of `bin`.

Comment: passing bin as any of the GET params

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: No, I can't and its too much to make generic. To fix the issue I determined if bin is one of the params and then added %20 to it like '%20bin' since I know its trimmed on the other side.

Comment: The reason I asked for sample code was because I was interested to know if `bin` was an endpoint issue or something related to what you were doing in the call. For example, does your endpoint get hit and then it returns a 404? Or does it not hit your code at all?

Answer (score 1):

I found an old article for IIS 6.0. Maybe it's still working: [StopBinFiltering](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/54e9382b-743d-495e-a324-b8b57a5214ee.mspx?mfr=true)

Setting the

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\

registry key can allow a malicious user access to programs and content in the /bin directory.

To disable /bin filtering:

1. In the details pane, right-click, point to New, and click DWORD Value.
2. In the Name box, type the following: StopBinFiltering.
3. Double-click the StopBinFiltering value, and in the Value data box type 1.
4. Click OK, and then close Registry Editor.
5. To reenable /bin filtering, set the StopBinFiltering value to 0.

Good luck